# R shiny reactive output not displaying

Tags: r, shiny, output

I have the following dataframe

```
  df<-data.frame("A"<-c(1:5), 'B'<-c("a", 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'))
  names(df)<-c('A', "B")
```

I have created a select box in R shiny UI and have also written the code for the server as below.

```
 ui<- fluidPage(
 selectInput(inputId = "input", label = "No of days elapsed", choices = 
 c(0:1000), selected = T, multiple =F  
 ),mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput("Output1")))

 server<-function(input, output){text<-reactive({number<-input$input
 number<-as.numeric(number)

  Y<-function(X){if(X<5){
  A<-df[!df$A==X,]} else {A<-df[df$A==(X-3),]}
  return (A)}
  out1<-Y(number)
  })
    renderPrint({text()$B})
    }
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The code generates the select box box. However, When i use the box and choose a number, there is no output. Also no error appears. I am not sure where my error is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code:

- You call `verbatimTextOutput("Output1")`, but `output$Output1` is not defined.
- You use `verbatimTextOutput`, while it seems you want to output a table, so you should use `dataTableOutput`.
- Also, formatting ;)

A working example is shown below. Hope this helps!

---

```
Y<-function(X){if(X<5){
  A<-df[!df$A==X,]} else {A<-df[df$A==(X-3),]}
  return (A)}

df<-data.frame("A"<-c(1:5), 'B'<-c("a", 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'))
names(df)<-c('A', "B")

ui<- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "input", label = "No of days elapsed", choices = 
                c(0:1000), selected = T, multiple =F  ),
  mainPanel(dataTableOutput("Output1"))
)

server<-function(input, output){
  text<-reactive({
    number<-input$input
    number<-as.numeric(number)
    out1<-Y(number)
  })
  output$Output1 <- renderDataTable({text()})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Yes Sir. I have added some details.

Answer (score 1):

Here is where I made a mistake.

```
     ui<- fluidPage(
      selectInput(inputId = "input", label = "No of days elapsed", choices = 
      c(0:1000), selected = T, multiple =F  
    ),mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput("Output1")))


      server<-function(input, output){text<-reactive({number<-input$input
      number<-as.numeric(number)

       Y<-function(X){if(X<5){
       A<-df[!df$A==X,]} else {A<-df[df$A==(X-3),]}
        return (A)}
       out1<-Y(number)
        } )
       **output$Output1<-renderPrint({text()$B})**
        }
       shinyApp(ui, server)
```

That generated the output. I had not assigned the output correctly

Comment: Ah, I see now what you were trying to do. My replacement of your verbatimtextoutput with datatableoutput was incorrect, glad you were able to resolve the issue :)

Comment: Actually your output looks impressive. I Wanted a dataframe generated by renderprint but after assigning the function inside. So that I managed with my code. However, I was able to get an alternate version also